# How to not calculate the hashcode each time value is inserted

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

I have implemented my own hashmap for study purposes. The key has a string and the value has an object of the class I created. By the way, I want to know if my hashcode method is appropriate, and how to not calculate the hashcode every time a value is inserted.

I saved the hash value once calculated as a member variable of object. However, when the get method is called, only the key value is received, so the hashcode must be obtained. How can I recycle the once calculated hash value?

- Finally, is my hash generation method appropriate?

```java
class IHashMap {

    private class Node {

        int hash;

        String key;
        int data;
        Node right;

        public Node(String key, int data) {

            this.key = key;
            this.data = data;
            this.right = null;
            this.hash = 0;
        }
    }
    private Node[] table;
    private int tbSize;
    private int n;

    public IHashMap(int tbSize) {

        this.table = new Node[tbSize];
        this.tbSize = tbSize;
        this.n = 0;
    }

    //...Omit irrelevant code...

    public void put(String key, int value) {

        int hash = hashCode(key);

        Node node = new Node(key, value);
        node.hash = hash;

        if(this.table[hash] != null) {

            Node entry = this.table[hash];

            while(entry.right != null && !entry.key.equals(key))
                entry = entry.right;

            if(entry.key.equals(key)) {

                entry.data++;
            }
            else {

                entry.right = node;
                this.n++;
            }
        }
        else {

            this.table[hash] = node;
            this.n++;
        }
    }

    public int get(String key) {

        int hash = hashCode(key);

        if(this.table[hash] != null) {

            if(this.table[hash].key.equals(key))
                return this.table[hash].data;

            Node entry = this.table[hash];

            while(entry != null && !entry.key.equals(key))
                entry = entry.right;

            if(entry == null)
                return -1;
            return entry.data;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int hash(String key) {

        int h = 0;
        if(key.length() > 0) {

            char[] var = strToCharArray(key);

            for(int i = 0; i < var.length; i++)
                h = 31 * h + var[i];
        }
        return h;
    }

    private int hashCode(String key) {

        return (hash(key) & 0x7fffffff) % this.tbSize;
    }

    //...Omit irrelevant code...
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could answer me.

Comment: Call `key.hashCode()`: String know how to compute its own hashCode, and caches its value.

Comment: Two parts of your question contradict. You want to implement a hash map. It means you **want** to use hash to quickly determine the position of the element during insertion and during looking up. On the other hand you want not to use hash. You cannot reach two goals at once. Of course you can postpone calculation e.g. by using a list and calculate hashes only when you look up. But this changes basically nothing.

Comment: If the object has only final fields, and is final itself, you could calculate the hash code at construction, and have the hashcode method return that.  Other things to consider here are do you need all of the fields of the object to define the objects "identity", if not you can simplify your hashcode and equals by only using those fields you absolutely need

Comment: Well ... I just want to know if my hashcode generation method is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the hashcode is the hashcode of the thing that is being inserted.

They way to prevent this from being too much of a hassle is to slip in lines into the storage items's hashcode that looks like

int hashcode() {
    if (I have a cached hashcode) {
      return cached_hashcode;
    }
    (calculate hashcode)
    cached_hashcode = hashcode;
    return hashcode;
  }

this way, for each object, you only go through the hashcode computation once.

Now, keep in mind that computers have progressed a lot.  They mostly wait on the RAM subsystem to respond to results, and can do about 1000 to 10000 math operations for a single ram fetch.  This means that "preserving CPU cycles" at the cost of memory look ups can actually slow down your program.

Benchmark wisely, and don't be afraid to use a little CPU if it means reducing your RAM footprint.

For those who are curious, if your program is small enough to fit into layer 1 cache, it's not a big delay, but as you spill over these caches into the other layers the delays become noticeable.  This is why "caching" is not always a great solution, as if you cache too heavily, your program becomes larger, and will spill out of cache more often.

Modern CPUs try to compensate, mostly by pre-fetching the needed RAM before it is requested (looking ahead in the processing stream).  That leads to better runtime in many cases, but also creates new issues (like preloading stuff you might not use because you chose the "other" path through the code).

The best bet is to not overly-cache stuff that is simple, unless it's expensive to reconstruct.  With the JVM a method call (at the very low levels) is more expensive than you might think, so the JVM has special optimizations for Strings and their hash codes.

Comment: Oh, and about your code.  The only problem I can see is that the hash is primarly used to locate which bucket (list of nodes) you start at.  After you pick that array entry of head nodes, you've saved the computational complexity you were trying to avoid.  As you can't rely on the hash for a correct reply, you have to do the equals on every item in that list of nodes anyway, so caching hashcodes for exact comparison usually doesn't help much.  The `.equals(...)` in the JVM is pretty heavily optimized for Strings already.

Comment: Thank Edwin Buck!
I agree that reckless caching is not a good solution.
The reason I'm caching is to get some time advantage when solving algorithm problems.

I devised separate chaining when creating the data structure above. But I was wondering if I implemented correctly. In particular, I'm not good at math so I don't know if collisions can happen or if the implementation is appropriate. Can you get feedback on these parts?

Comment: @Taylous But you're not getting any time advantage.  To use this kind of caching, you're taking a time disadvantage and a memory disadvantage.  The hash decides "which" linked list of items you start at.  But because there are more different string values than different int values, you always need to check the key (string) to the key in the node: a matching hash doesn't avoid string equality checks.  A decent hash doesn't put "nearly" the same strings in the same hash, so odds are just comparing the first 4 bytes (what optimized string equals start with) is faster than comparing hash & string